# (C#) YouTube API v3 - Copyright Strikes?

Tags: c#, youtube-api

I'm using the Google YouTube API v3 to automate checking for Copyright Strikes on several YouTube channels. The `ChannelAuditDetails` class provides a `CopyrightStrikesGoodStanding` boolean variable for whether or not there are any Copyright Strikes, but I'm also hoping to check the total number of strikes (if any) should the `CopyrightStrikesGoodStanding` be false (indicating that there are strikes).

Where can this information be found within the API? Is it even there? I am working within C#.

Comment: I like how the Google API pages direct you to post questions about it here, and then answers almost never happen.

Comment: I don't think that information is available through the API, there's nothing about it in the docs or source.